# Why does Openfire keep reloading my plugin

Tags: plugins, jetty, init, openfire

I creating a plugin for Openfire, and there are some initialization steps in the method `initializePlugin`.

The initialization steps of my plugin are supposed to run only once.
But I find that Openfire keeps repeating the call to `initializePlugin` of my plugin after
each ~20 seconds. This is strange!

Is it a Jetty or Openfire problem?
How to tell Openfire to call `initializePlugin` just 1 time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dele Olajide:

I found the problem. I was able to replicate it on a Linux Centos box.

It happens when the timestamp on the plugin file is higher than the timestamp on the folder created when the plugin is unzipped. It can happen if the you are developing on a PC which is in a different time-zone.

Check the date/timestamp. If higher than the current date/time, then touch the file to reset timestamp to current date/time.

Answer taken from:
http://community.igniterealtime.org/message/224340